# how to get a empty space at the end of the code in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimetext4

In Sublime Text I don't have blank space at the end of the code and I'm sad because it's really cool.
do you know if there is a way to get it naturally, without entering 15 empty lines at the end ?
[a lot of useless rows after the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eERYC.png)
[cozy empty space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EWXf.png)

I tried searching on google and on Stackoverflow "sublime blank/empty space text at end of code" and more variations but couldn't find anything on the subject
I looked in the settings if there was a simple variable to get it but didn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can scroll past the last line in a file by adding the following line to your user settings:

```json
    "scroll_past_end": true,
```

Comment: Thank you !
find the line (and just above "// On Mac, this value is overridden ...", i'm on mac) and i was able to copy past the setting in users-settings